# How to get responseText from JavaScript Variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

Code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var filepath = 'csv/data.csv';                      
        var data_string = $.get(filepath);
        console.log(data_string);
    });
</script>
```

When I use `console.log(data_string)` I got the following output on the console.

When I read that, I found that "responseText" has the values which I want. So I just need to get "responseText" to another variable.

I tried `var data = data_string.responseText`. But it not worked.

[image]

Comment: var responseText = data_string[responseText]

Comment: @HarshPatel — That won't work.

Comment: Have you considered [reading the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) which has examples?

Comment: It is working for you ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Yes. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should attach a `callback` function to `$.get`. From your console i see that is a `jqXHR Object`. `$.get` method has a `success` callback function that is executed if the `request` succeeds.

`Attaching` a callback function includes automatically `json` parsed.

```
var filepath = 'csv/data.csv';    
$.get( filepath , function(response) {
   console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide callback function to get response from server like below:

```
var filepath = 'csv/data.csv';    
$.get( filepath , function( data ) {
 console.log(data);
});
```